# Start Xen domU automatically and connect console when dom0 boots

Tags: xen

Is anyone aware of a way to connect to the console (like using xm create -c) of a domU that's set to start automatically upon dom0 boot, such that the user only saw the login prompt of the domU when the machine finished booting?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want the physical console of the dom0 to only show a login console of the domU? How do you plan to administer the machine if you need physical access?

What about creating a user on the dom0 that has its shell set to connect to the console of the domU? That way you can give the users of the machine this account and then they can login to their domU.

Answer (score 0):

Console is, what the names says, a 'console' link to the domU. The point of having a console is just to see the output of the boot process otherwise i suggest you to give raw ssh access (using keys)